# How to put the axis definition in the preamble?

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I have to create a presentation with lots of diagrams. I do this with the beamer class and pgfplots.
I'm tired of copying the axis definition in every single diagram and I'm looking for a way to put it in the preamble of the presentation file. 
Tried to create a newcommand \axisdefintion but this didn't work.

Is there a way to have the axis definition in the preamble (except for the title)?

This is what such a diagram would look like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Some Title here},
    every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
    width=\textwidth,
    axis line style=thin,%Achsenstärke
    filter discard warning=false,
    axis line style={gray!30},
    axis y line = center,
    axis x line = center,
    y tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}, anchor=east},
    x tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}, anchor=north},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,-0.03)},anchor=north, font={\tiny}},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south, font={\tiny}},
    xlabel=Zeit in ms,
    ylabel=Sensorwerte,
    every y tick/.style={gray!30},
    ytick={-550,-500,...,1350},
    xtick={0,1000,...,12840},
    no markers,
    every axis plot/.append style={thin},
    every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily},
    axis on top=false,
    font={\sffamily},
    xmin=0, xmax=12900,
    ymin=-550, ymax=1360,
    legend style={fill=none, draw=none, at={(1.1,0.05)},anchor=east,font={\fontsize{4}{2}\selectfont}, /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=5pt},},
    legend columns=2,
    legend cell align={left},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{2}\selectfont, color={DarkRed}},
    ]
    %%Plots
    %%add some plots here
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374693/creating-and-using-styles-in-pgfplots, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36143/axis-limits-in-user-defined-style?rq=1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That easy? Ok. This helped a lot. Thank you.